# Compose pressed state vs tap

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

we are implementing a design system, where the UI people gave us different colors and other resources to apply on a Composable according to its "state".

Let's say I have a simple Card composable, my zeplin says :

- on pressed : Color.Red
- on hover : Color.Green
- on tap : Color.Blue
- on drag : Color.Magenta

Everything worked fine until we bumped a bunch of versions (material3 & compose), now as soon as I press on my view, the onPressed token applies, there used to be a delay until it showed, so there was a real difference between a simple tap/click and a user keeping their finger down on the view.

Any idea what happened and how I can correct it ? Don't hesitate to roast this method and give me arguments as to why it's not a good practice.

Thx !

A bit of code :

```
@Composable
private fun CardImpl(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isEnabled: Boolean,
    resources: CardComponentData,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {

    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val isHovered by interactionSource.collectIsHoveredAsState()

    val backgroundColor = when {
        isEnabled.not() -> resources.disabledBackgroundColor
        isHovered -> resources.hoveredBackgroundColor
        isPressed -> resources.pressedBackgroundColor
        else -> resources.defaultBackgroundColor
    }

    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(resources.borderRadius.dp)

    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(shape)
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = rememberRipple(color = resources.pressedBackgroundColor),
                onClick = {},
            ),
        shape = shape,
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = backgroundColor,
        ),
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onClick = onClick,
        content = {
        // ...
        }
    )
}
```